# Spring Boot Filter error, Failed to register after unregistered Filter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, filter, kotlin

Im both new to Spring Boot and Kotlin.

I'm having an error saying that

```
Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Cannot register after unregistered Filter class com.jxinternet.platform.ms.merchant.config.security.ReplaceResponseFilter


2018-10-03 15:50:21.601 ERROR 63436 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot register after unregistered Filter class com.jxinternet.platform.ms.merchant.config.security.ReplaceResponseFilter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:587)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1250)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1099)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243)
    at com.jxinternet.platform.ms.merchant.MerchantApplicationKt.main(MerchantApplication.kt:28)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot register after unregistered Filter class com.jxinternet.platform.ms.merchant.config.security.ReplaceResponseFilter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot register after unregistered Filter class com.jxinternet.platform.ms.merchant.config.security.ReplaceResponseFilter
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.FilterComparator.registerAfter(FilterComparator.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity.addFilterAfter(HttpSecurity.java:1121)
    at com.jxinternet.platform.ms.merchant.config.security.WebSecurityConfig.configure(WebSecurityConfig.kt:64)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.getHttp(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:230)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:321)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.init(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:92)
    at com.jxinternet.platform.ms.merchant.config.security.WebSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7e2d609b.init(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:371)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:325)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5effa1c.CGLIB$springSecurityFilterChain$3(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5effa1c$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d83091e8.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f5effa1c.springSecurityFilterChain(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 21 common frames omitted

Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51914', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

my ReplaceResponseFilter.kt

```
package com.jxinternet.platform.ms.merchant.config.security

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order
import org.springframework.hateoas.VndErrors
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder
import org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean
import javax.servlet.*
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper


open class ReplaceResponseFilter : Filter {

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ReplaceResponseFilter::class.java)
    }

    override fun doFilter(request: ServletRequest, response: ServletResponse, filterChain: FilterChain) {

        val t = response as HttpServletResponseWrapper


    }

    override fun init(p0: FilterConfig?) {
        TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
    }

    override fun destroy(){

    }


}
```

my WebSecurityConfig.kt

```
package com.jxinternet.platform.ms.merchant.config.security

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
import org.springframework.security.web.firewall.HttpFirewall
import org.springframework.security.web.firewall.StrictHttpFirewall



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
class WebSecurityConfig(
        private val tokenAuthenticationService: TokenAuthenticationService,
        private val objectMapper: ObjectMapper
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    // 防止防止url带两个// spring security 5会有问题 所以必须放开这个配置
    @Bean
    fun allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall(): HttpFirewall {
        val firewall = StrictHttpFirewall()
        firewall.setAllowUrlEncodedSlash(true)
        return firewall
    }

    override fun configure(web: WebSecurity) {
        super.configure(web)
        web.httpFirewall(allowUrlEncodedSlashHttpFirewall())
    }

    // 设置 HTTP 验证规则
    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
        // 关闭csrf验证
        http.csrf().disable()
                // 对请求进行认证
                .authorizeRequests()
                // 所有 / 的所有请求 都放行
                .antMatchers(
                        "/",
                        "/pay/**",
                        "/scan/**",
                        "/login",
                        "/actuator/health",
                        "/webjars/springfox-swagger-ui/**",
                        "/swagger-ui.html",
                        "/configuration/ui",
                        "/swagger-resources",
                        "/v2/api-docs",
                        "/swagger-resources/**").permitAll()
                // 所有 /login 的POST请求 都放行
                // 所有请求需要身份认证
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // 添加一个过滤器 所有访问 /login 的请求交给 JWTLoginFilter 来处理 这个类处理所有的JWT相关内容
                //.addFilterBefore(loginFilter(objectMapper, tokenAuthenticationService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
                // 添加一个过滤器验证其他请求的Token是否合法
                .addFilterBefore(JWTAuthenticationFilter(tokenAuthenticationService, objectMapper), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
                .addFilterAfter(ReplaceResponseFilter(), ReplaceResponseFilter::class.java)
                // 设置session无状态！！
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `ReplaceResponseFilter`, you're missing:

```
filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
```

Otherwise, your filter chain cannot continue.
I also believe that this is incorrect:

```
.addFilterAfter(ReplaceResponseFilter(), ReplaceResponseFilter::class.java)
```

As far as I understand your code, that filter should come after `JWTAuthenticationFilter`. Therefore:

```
.addFilterAfter(ReplaceResponseFilter(), JWTAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
```

Comment: THanks @Branislav Lazic it works, however i only realized it runs after the JWTAuthenticationFilter but before entering the servlet(impl). But I want is run(my replaceresponsefilter) after it goes finished through the servlet(impl). Do you know wat i need to do? i still looking for it.